# cURL request in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a question regarding cURL requests in PHP. I have to use cURL requests but haven't been in touch with them at all.

In the following example I will show you how I see the cURL request. My question is: How do I "convert" this statement into a PHP cURL request?

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer APIKEY" "https://api.example.com/api-api-ng/v1/function?lat=50&lon=8&radius=500&statement=2"
```

So I hope you guys can help me with this problem. I only know the basics of cURL  and hope you can show me all steps required to set up a cURL request.

Comment: Read about `curl_setopt()` to do the same call in php as under linux.

Comment: Check out the manual for [`PHP cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and for the command line usage of [`cURL`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). That should help you "convert" it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.example.com/api-api-ng/v1/function?lat=50&lon=8&radius=500&statement=2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer APIKEY";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thank you very mich for the quick response!