# submit form using post method from custom website

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

We have this website where user can check his/her results.
http://202.166.206.52:4443/itms/check_results

I am looking forward to make form in my own webiste and when user click submit on custom made website, it will then get input values and show the results using above website on my own custom website.

I am looking only to modify if there is no record of student, then it will show reponse on same webiste with some animation and if there is record of marksheet..it will display results over webiste as overlay. How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, you'll have to use cURL , and hit http://202.166.206.52:4443/itms/check_results/searchResults/ with POST request, that contains these fields:

```
src_year
src_level
exam_symbol_number
dob
submit=Search
```

For any clarification on how cURL works, see [cURL request in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005798/curl-request-in-php)